# Nano path to save cursor position and searchs

Tags: configuration, nano

Anytime I exit the nano editor, I get an error like this:

> Unable to create directory /home/oloco/.config/local/share/nano/: No
> such file or directory It is required for saving/loading search
> history or cursor positions

Is there a way in order to configure the path so that I dont have to save it in that place?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The user data directory, normally at `~/.local/share` (not `~/.config/local/share` – that's already custom), is configured through the `XDG_DATA_HOME` environment variable.

Current versions of nano will look in `~/.nano/` first, before trying `$XDG_DATA_HOME/nano/` followed by `$HOME/.local/share/nano/`.

Similarly, the configuration is loaded from `~/.nanorc`, then `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nano/nanorc`, finally `~/.config/nano/nanorc`.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your time and advices. All you say is true, so I had a look to my old zshenv file for zsh, and I realized that somehow $XDG_DATA_HOME was set like that:

export XDG_DATA_HOME="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/local/share"

So it was my fault, and not nano's config issue.

Thanks in advance!!